# Cross between multiple images on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, gif

the first example in the link below but with hover. It explains with just two images. But I want multiple images...
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/
Then I want it to play backward on the mouse out.

I tried solving this by replacing the second image with a gif, but there is an issue. because a gif just plays once or infinite. And if you want to play again, you should load it again which is inefficient. I don't think it's possible to replay a gif or play it backward with HTML/CSS or javascript. is it?

Answer (score 0):

We’re going to look at some techniques that enable us use HTML5 video as a drop in replacement for animated GIFs. We’ll learn how to convert animated GIFs to video files and examine how to properly embed these video files on the web so that they act just like a GIF would.

**First of all gif convert to mp4**

```
ffmpeg -i animated.gif video.mp4
```

**Also to webm**

```
ffmpeg -i animated.gif -c vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 41 video.webm
```

**Replace Animated GIFs With Video**

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
   <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Now video act as GIF

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But I was thinking about another solution involved making a sprite sheet from images and handle it with CSS animation. I think with  sprite sheet the size of the file would be smaller.

Comment: What do you do after you convert it to video? how do you handle this:
on hover plays and the pause at the last frame after hove play in reverse.